# Post php variable to multiple other files at same moment

Tags: php, ajax

Below code post myid variable to url.php.

```
$.ajax({
url:'url.php' //'url.php,test.php' is invalid
,async: true
,type : 'POST'
,cache: false
,data : 'myid=' + myid
,dataType: 'html'
,success: function(data){
$('body').html(data);
FB.XFBML.parse();
}
}
```

How can I post it to multiple other files at same moment? I need myid in various files also.

Comment: You can hit only one url at a time not multiple url same time.

Comment: You cannot send multiple Requests at one time (at least I am not aware of such a thing, it is http protocol (request - response). So your best shot is to send your data to a proxy (php file) which sends the data to other files. Or you subsequential send the data one after another.

Comment: Why do you want exactly to do it at the same moment? Why don't just send for each url with loop?

Comment: @Arantir: thanks but how in loop? I just want to send `myid` var to some php files using post@

Answer (score 1):

```
function send(_url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _url
        ,async: true
        ,type : 'POST'
        ,cache: false
        ,data : 'myid=' + myid
        ,dataType: 'html'
        ,success: function(data){
            $('body').html(data);
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        }
    }
}

['url.php','test.php'].forEach(send);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your url.php make a curl POST request to other PHP files as needed